# How convert 'tuple' object to str

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm trying make a search field in my app. First I want load all results, but if user request the search, show only your answer.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    pista = self.request.GET.get('pesquisar_por')

    sql = (
    "SELECT t1.codigo, t1.nome, t1.quantidade, t1.preco_venda, t2.nome as nome_grupo "+
    "FROM produto t1 "+
    "LEFT JOIN grupo t2 on (t1.grupo = t2.codigo) "+
    "WHERE t1.status= 'A' ")
    if pista is not None:
        sql = sql + ("AND t1.nome LIKE %s", ['%'+pista+'%'])
    sql = sql + "ORDER BY t1.nome LIMIT 300"
    produtos = Produto.objects.using('horus').raw(sql)
    return produtos
```

But this showed this error: **Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly**.

The error is in this line: sql = sql + ("AND t1.nome LIKE %s", ['%'+pista+'%'])

Comment: `("AND t1.nome LIKE %s", ['%'+pista+'%'])` is creating a tuple

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. I'm begginer in Python/Django it's my first time using tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you sql concatenation and excution should be like this instead:

```
sql = sql + "AND t1.nome LIKE %%s%"
```

and then pass your parameters in the `.raw()` method like:

```
produtos = Produto.objects.using('horus').raw(sql, [pista])
```

I don't remember if you need to *escape* the `%` by using `%%%s%%` instead of just `%%s%`, but you should definitely pass parameters using the method signature rather than concatenating things yourself to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Check this as reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw

P.S. You probably have your reasons to use raw sql instead of the ORM, but I'd reccommend to first exhaust the ways you could use the ORM instead of raw sql. It's up to you, though.

Comment: Thanks Gerard, I'm using because I've other system with those tables. You solved my problem, but I have had that edit a little your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
if pista is not None:
    sql = sql + "AND t1.nome LIKE %{pista}%".format(pista=pista)
```

This **will not conver a tuple in str** but could help.

Comment: Ok, sorry for named of my question, I'm begginer in Django and back-end systems, I don't know most concepts.